# How can I filter mailboxes that have never been logged on in Exchange Management Shell?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to run a Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics command across a large number of mailboxes but the majority have never been used as it is a new install. As a result, I have to sit through hundreds of lines of

```
WARNING: There is no data to return for the specified mailbox '<mailbox DN>' because it has not been logged on to.
```

It would seem that I need to use a server-side filter of some kind but I haven't been able to find anything appropriate.

What can I do here?

Answer (score 1):

There is no server side filtering in Get-MailboxStatistics and I can't repro it. Can you try this:

Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxStatistics -warningAction silentlyContinue

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard PS behavior for warnings.  You can find Shay's parameter in the help for common_parameters `get-help about_common_parameters`.  Alternately, you can set `$WarningPreference = silentlycontinue`.  There are no statistics to return as the mailboxes have not yet been initialized, hence the warning.